# WebApi and Angular 2+ - Authentication - Token expired - Return to login

Tags: angular, authentication, access-token, webapi

I have a angular client application protected by a login. When I log in, the web API returns me the access token that expire in x minutes.
When the access token is expired I want return to the login but I do not understand how to do it.

This is my `ErrorInterceptor` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
            // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
            this.authenticationService.logout();                
            location.reload(true);
        }
        
        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
    }))
  }
}
```

But when token is expired nothing happens.

Someone can give me some advice?

Comment: The web api that generates your token should also check that the token is valid. If it's expired, it should return an error which would be picked up on the front end to redirect you. Alternatively, when you receive the token back from the api, it could also send an expiry date. Store that expiry date wherever you are keeping the token, and then if the current date is greater than the expiry date, delete the token, and redirect to the login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HttpInterceptor:

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

In Angular create an Interceptor that will check for errStatus 401 (Unauthorized).

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private logoutService: LogoutService) { /* empty */ }

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err && err.status) {

                this.handleRequestErrors(err.status);
            }

            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
    }

    /**
     * handleRequestErrors
     * @param err: The HTTP Error Code Status
     */
    private handleRequestErrors(errStatus: number) {
        switch (errStatus) {
            case 401: { // Unauthorized
                this.logoutService.removeStoredAuthentication();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my ErrorInterceptor class, but when token is expired nothing happens

Comment: You should be sending the token to the API on every request. The API should be returning the Unauthorized error code if the token is expired. If you wired the Interceptor class correctly then it should work.